# JS execute before data loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't understand something. I have a js code in the $(document).ready() function.

I got:

```
function functionTest() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2");
    if (elem != null) {
        var dummyevent = new Array();
        dummyevent["target"] = elem;
        dummyevent["srcElement"] = elem;
        elem.parentNode.click();
        WpClick(dummyevent);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    functionTest();
}
```

if i execute the function in the js console, it work.

I try:

```
setInterval(functionTest, 1000);
```

and the code works but i don't want to use an interval, cause of the "click".

Why is the code not execute the way i want it ?

I have an another code with the same problemes:

```
$("myClass").css("color", "#a778ae")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2010 or 2013? You should look in to `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` or `SP.SOD.executeFunc` depending on version:

> SharePoint 2013 Code:
>
> ```
> SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', sharePointReady);
>
> function sharePointReady() {
>    alert("Ready");
> }
> ```
>
> SharePoint 2010 Code:
>
> ```
> ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(sharePointReady, "sp.js");
>
> function sharePointReady() {
>    alert("Ready");
> }
> ```

Source: http://www.mahmoudfarhat.net/post/2013/03/23/SharePoint-2013-ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded-not-executing-after-page-publish.aspx

Comment: That's work for $("myClass").css("color", "#a778ae") but it doesn't for the other function. The function is loaded (console.log("function !!!")) but it doesn't affect anything.

Comment: I put a setTimeout(myFunction, 2000) ... it work